# How to randomly select data from multiple aligned dataset in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow-datasets

Supposing we have 6 text files in 2 groups and each group consists of 3 files, say,

- group 1: 1.a, 1.b, 1.c
- group 2: 2.a, 2.b, 2.c

given a fixed threshold `rand`, and `random()` from `random` module, what I wish to get is 3 tensors:

- group x: x_a, x_b, x_c

where the number of lines in each file is the same and aligned, and nth row of x_a will be:

- Step 1: `'<nth line from 1.a>' if rand < random() else '<nth line from 2.a>'`

also nth row of x_b and x_c will be:

- Step 2: `<'nth line from 1.b>' if '<nth row of x_a from 1.a>' else '<nth line from 2.b>'`
- Step 3: `<'nth line from 1.c>' if '<nth row of x_a from 1.a>' else '<nth line from 2.c>'` (follow Step 2 but apply to x_c)

so that x_a, x_b, and x_c are all aligned.

The tool I am using is `tf.data.TextLineDataset`, could you tell me how can I make the random selection and keep the selection track? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

======================== MY SOLUTION ========================

I provided a track file to guide these 3 files. Still welcome other solutions!

```
a1 = tf.data.TextLineDataset(afile1).map(...)
b1 = tf.data.TextLineDataset(bfile1).map(...)
c1 = tf.data.TextLineDataset(cfile1).map(...)
...
index = tf.data.TextLineDataset(track_file).map(lambda line: tf.string_to_number(line, tf.int32))
As = tf.data.Dataset.zip((index, a1, a2))
Bs = tf.data.Dataset.zip((index, b1, b2))
...
ax = As.map(lambda i, l, r: tf.where(i > 0, l, r))
bx = As.map(lambda i, l, r: tf.where(i > 0, l, r))
cx = As.map(lambda i, l, r: tf.where(i > 0, l, r))
...
```